# GLSL normals change with a camera rotation

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lighting, normals

I know that same questions were asked many times, but unfortunately I am unable to find the source of my problem.

With help of tutorials I've written a small GLSL shader. Right now it can work with ambient light and load normals from normal map. The issue is that directional light seems to be dependent on my viewing angle.
Here are my shaders:

```
//Vertex Shader
#version 120
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec3 tangent;

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying mat3 tbnMatrix;
uniform mat4 transform;
void main(){
 gl_Position=transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
 texCoord0 = texCoord;
 vec3 n = normalize((transform*vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz);
 vec3 t = normalize((transform*vec4(tangent,0.0)).xyz);
 t=normalize(t-dot(t,n)*n);
 vec3 btTangent=cross(t,n);
 tbnMatrix=transpose(mat3(t,btTangent,n));
}


//Fragment Shader
#version 120
varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying mat3 tbnMatrix;
struct BaseLight{
  vec3 color;
  float intensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight{
  BaseLight base;
  vec3 direction;
};

uniform sampler2D diffuse;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform vec3 ambientLight;
uniform DirectionalLight directionalLight;

vec4 calcLight(BaseLight base, vec3 direction,vec3 normal){
  float diffuseFactor=dot(normal,normalize(direction));
  vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0,0,0,0);
  if(diffuseFactor>0){
    diffuseColor=vec4(base.color,1.0)* base.intensity *diffuseFactor;
  }

  return diffuseColor;
}
vec4 calcDirectionalLight(DirectionalLight directionalLight ,vec3 normal){
    return calcLight(directionalLight.base,directionalLight.direction,normal);
}

void main(){

    vec3 normal =tbnMatrix*(255.0/128.0* texture2D(normalMap,texCoord0).xyz-255.0/256.0);
    vec4 totalLight = vec4(ambientLight,0)   +calcDirectionalLight(directionalLight, normal);
    gl_FragColor=texture2D(diffuse,texCoord0)*totalLight;
}
```

"transform" matrix that I send to the shader is summarily computed this way:

```
viewProjection=m_perspective* glm::lookAt(CameraPosition,CameraPosition+m_forward,m_up);
glm::mat4 transform = vievProjection * object_matrix;
```

"object_matrix" is a matrix that I get directly from physics engine.(I think it's the matrix that defines position and rotation of the object in the world space, correct me if I'm wrong.)

And I guess that "transform" matrix is computed correctly, since all the objects are drawn in the right positions. It looks like the problem is related to normals because if I set gl_FragColor = vec4(normal, 0) the color is also changing with camera rotation.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could point me to my mistake

Comment: The normal is a vector (direction), not a point, and cannot be transformed with your `transform` matrix. You'll probably want a separate inverse transpose of your camera matrix. A search for 'normal transform' should give you the theory, examples, etc.

Comment: `n` and `t` should only be transformed with the `object_matrix`. Then both normals and light parameters are in world space.

Comment: @BrettHale Thank you, I did as you said and used 'transpose(inverse(mat))' in computation of my normals and I think it works. At least now the light is clearly coming from one direction and does not change because of my camera rotation. There are some strange illuminated  parts on the mesh, but I think it's because right now I can't check whether the light should be applied or not. But basic cube model works great. So thanks.